# Jquery open multiple dialogs and make background responsive to actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating web app that should use multiple dialogs controlled by user. The problem is that there is some kind of layer that doesn't allow me to touch the background elements. Try to click some of the links when a dialog is open. How to fix it? Also i have a error when trying to create other dialogs with link click.

```js
$(function() {
  function addButtons(dlg) {
    // Define Buttons
    var $close = dlg.find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
    var $min = $("<button>", {
      class: "ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-window-minimize",
      type: "button",
      title: "Minimize"
    }).insertBefore($close);
    $min.data("isMin", false);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"
    }).appendTo($min);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-button-icon-space"
    }).html(" ").appendTo($min);
    var $max = $("<button>", {
      class: "ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-window-maximize",
      type: "button",
      title: "Maximize"
    }).insertBefore($close);
    $max.data("isMax", false);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"
    }).appendTo($max);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-button-icon-space"
    }).html(" ").appendTo($max);
    // Define Function
    $min.click(function(e) {
      if ($min.data("isMin") === false) {
        console.log("Minimize Window");
        $min.data("original-pos", dlg.position());
        $min.data("original-size", {
          width: dlg.width(),
          height: dlg.height()
        });
        $min.data("isMin", true);
        dlg.animate({
          height: '40px',
          top: $(window).height() - 50
        }, 200);
        dlg.find(".ui-dialog-content").hide();
      } else {
        console.log("Restore Window");
        $min.data("isMin", false);
        dlg.find(".ui-dialog-content").show();
        dlg.animate({
          height: $min.data("original-size").height + "px",
          top: $min.data("original-pos").top + "px"
        }, 200);
      }
    });
    $max.click(function(e) {
      if ($max.data("isMax") === false) {
        console.log("Maximize Window");
        $max.data("original-pos", dlg.position());
        $max.data("original-size", {
          width: dlg.width(),
          height: dlg.height()
        });
        $max.data("isMax", true);
        dlg.animate({
          height: $(window).height() -28+ "px",
          width: $(window).width()-10 + "px",
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        }, 200);
      } else {
        console.log("Restore Window");
        $max.data("isMax", false);
        dlg.animate({
          height: $max.data("original-size").height + "px",
          width: $max.data("original-size").width + "px",
          top: $max.data("original-pos").top + "px",
          left: $max.data("original-pos").top + "px"
        }, 200);
      }
    });
  }

  $('#window').dialog({
    draggable: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    classes: {
      "ui-dialog": "ui-window-options",
      "ui-dialog-titlebar": "ui-window-bar"
    },
    modal: true,
    responsive: true,
  });

  addButtons($(".ui-window-options"));

  $("#winOpener").click(function() {
    $("#window").dialog("open");
  })
   $("#winOpener1").click(function() {
    $("#window1").dialog("open");
  })
   $("#winOpener2").click(function() {
    $("#window2").dialog("open");
  })
});
```

```css
 .ui-window-bar .ui-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 20px;
}

.ui-window-bar .ui-window-minimize {
  right: calc(.3em + 40px);
}

.ui-window-bar .ui-window-maximize {
  right: calc(.3em + 20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CrazyTuna/jquery-extendeddialog/master/src/fq-ui.extendeddialog.js"></script>
    
<a href="#" id="winOpener">Open Window</a>
<a href="#" id="winOpener1">Open Window</a>
<a href="#" id="winOpener2">Open Window</a>
<div id="window" title="Test Window">window</div>
<div id="window1" title="Test Window1">window</div>
<div id="window2" title="Test Window2">window</div>
```

Comment: `modal: true` means the dialog blocks access to the rest of the page.